# Grafana Worldmap-Panel threshold options not working

Tags: grafana, world-map

I am using grafana-worldmap-panel to display information store in influxdb. I've store geohash, and val(0-10) as field in influxdb. Data points is being display properly.

[image]

I also have specified thresholds which is not working.

[image]

Though val has 0-10 values, all data-points are appearing green. If I checked "With only nulls" under Hide Series all data points disappears.

I'm I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting an alias to the field worked for me

[image]